# Anyone have experience with slide.show2?

Tags: .net, silverlight, slideshow, slide.show2

I'm looking to use [Slide.Show2](http://slideshow2.codeplex.com/) on a website, however I have run into a few problems, and I am wondering if they are worth fighting through or not?

Problems Thus Far:

1. XmlDataProvider does not support query string parameters in the Path argument.  While I've managed to hack around it, this raises some serious warning flags to me about the maturity/quality of the source.
2. Right now the app appears to be crashing, Not sure if it's worth troubleshooting or not.

If not Slide.Show2 can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have access to the source code, so if anything isn't working to your liking, you can change.

You can also try contacting the author(s) to see if they can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented slide.show 2 with the FlickR API and it is working great. I had one problem tho, I tried asking for help on CodePlex, but it looks like the project is dead. I don't think there will be a lot support coming from there. I think your best shot is to fiddle around in the source yourself.